# Checking if PATH contains $HOME/mydir and adding it if not (all in a script)

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, path, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [keep duplicates out of $PATH on source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/keep-duplicates-out-of-path-on-source)

Some of my scripts are located in `$HOME/mydir`. Unfortunately, they are not accessible from elsewhere if this dir is not part of `PATH`.

I would like to create a small scripts checking whether `$HOME/mydir` is part of `PATH`. If it is not, `PATH` should be updated with it and `EXPORTED`.

My question is: which command can I use to check whether `$HOME/mydir` is part of `PATH`? Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

For the records, I implemented the following:

```
echo "Before: $PATH"

echo $PATH | grep -q "$HOME/scripts"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH=$PATH:$HOME/scripts
  export PATH
else
  export PATH
fi

echo ""
echo "After: $PATH"
```

Comment: are you sure this works? I made a typo in my response, which I have now edited. The exit code is in the $? variable, not $0, which should be the name of your script. Change `$0 == 0` to `$? -eq 0`. You should try it with a some path that is not in your PATH

Comment: It worked on my limited tests, but I have updated my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a simple bash script to do something like this.

```
echo $PATH | grep -q  "/your/search/path"
```

Then check if $? is not 0, meaning no match, and if so add the path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/your/search/path
```

Comment: $0 ?? is it right way to do?

Comment: @NikhilMulley, no it's not ... it's a typo, should be `$?`.

Comment: [glennjackman's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32054/9537) is the more correct way to do this.

Comment: @jw013: there is no correct, on incorrect way to do it, there is ways that work and ways that do not, and I think the grep way works.  Maybe you meant that using grep in this case waste a process, but I think it is very clean and easy to understand, so it is fine if performance is not an issue. Maybe you also meant that it might break if a subdirectory of `/your/search/path` is in your path, but it can easily be fixed (thanks to glennjackman idea of `:`). It can even be simplified as: `grep -q  ":/your/search/path:" <<< ":$PATH:" || export PATH=$PATH:/your/search/path`.

Comment: @jfgagne There are certainly better and worse ways to do things.  The `case` statement is a shell built-in - it's better for at least two reasons: (1) no external dependencies and (2) it doesn't need to fork a new process (slightly better performance).  So far you haven't proved your point as you've only pointed out that using `grep` can get similar results, but you have not mentioned any **advantages** of using `grep` over `case`.

Comment: @jw013: I think the grep solution is more readable.  Moreover, it fits on one line. I would not use it to add 10.000 elements to my PATH, but for a single addition, it fits most needs. ;-)

Answer (score 27):

I would write

```
case ":$PATH:" in
  *:$HOME/mydir:*) echo it is in the path;;
  *) echo not there ;;
esac
```

I write ":$PATH:" to ensure that the pattern matches if the desired path is either first or last in your $PATH.

Comment: right way to do things with $PATH stuff.

Comment: Great one on `:$PATH:` as it also make sure that none of `$HOME/mydir/subdir` or `$HOME/mydirectroy` is in the path.  +1.

Comment: That’s short, readable, clever – and POSIX compatible to boot!