# Can someone clarify: 'case ":$PATH:" in' in script?

Tags: shell-script

An answer to another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32041/checking-if-path-contains-home-mydir-and-adding-it-if-not-all-in-a-script#comment43484_32041) suggests using the following piece of code in a script:

```
case ":$PATH:" in
  *:$HOME/mydir:*) echo it is in the path;;
  *) echo not there ;;
esac
```

The purpose of this code is to check whether `$HOME/mydir` is in `$PATH`, but the examples in [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/case-esac-statement.htm) and [this](http://steve-parker.org/sh/case.shtml) suggest exact 'matching' rather than 'contains'.

How is 'case' operating here? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`case` is an exact match, but `*` means "match anything", and the case starts and ends with a `*`, so it will match any string that contains `:$HOME/mydir:`. The second case will match anything, but only if the first condition didn't match