# Why does the "which" command give duplicate results?

Tags: shell, path, which

`which -a ruby` gives me

```
/usr/ruby
/usr/ruby
/usr/ruby
```

It gives the same path three times. Why does this happen?

Comment: A hint: http://pastebin.com/8HNbDvnD. Some solutions: [keep duplicates out of $PATH on source](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/keep-duplicates-out-of-path-on-source)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your path.  It's not that hard to end up with duplicates in it. Example:

```
»echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:
»which -a bash
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash
```

This is because my /bin is a symlink to /usr/bin.  Now:

```
»export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
»echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
»which -a bash
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash
```

Since /usr/bin is now in my $PATH twice, `which -a` finds the same bash twice.

Comment: To expand: The -a option reports ALL matches in your PATH. That's what it's for. If, as noted, your $PATH references the same place more than once, or the same executable is in more than one place, it'll show up multiple times with -a (but not when omitting that option).

Answer (score 2):

As the hint says, and quoting from the manual page, `"Which takes one or more arguments. For each of its arguments it prints to stdout the full path of the executables that would have been executed when this argument
       had been entered at the shell prompt. It does this by searching for an executable or script in the directories listed in the environment variable PATH using the same
       algorithm as bash(1)."` As for the `-a` option, it lists all the executables by that name found in $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your path:

```
echo $PATH
```

There are duplicate entries in your path (or ruby is installed several times in different locations).

Answer (score 1):

Try

`whereis -b ruby`

If you are getting the same output, then the problem is in your PATH.